# Google sheet formulae for calculate gross salary

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

If basic<10000 calculate gross=DA+basic, if basic>=10000 and <20000 , calculate
gross=DA+basic+50% of HRA, if basic >=20000, calculate gross = basic+DA+HRA

Can anyone suggest google sheet formulae?

```
if(basic < 10000 )
{
   gross = DA + basic
}else if(basic >= 10000 && basic < 20000)
{
    gross = DA + basic + (0.5 * HRA)
}else
{
    gross = DA + basic + HRA
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just plug it to an `IF` formula.

```
=if(basic < 10000, DA + basic, if(and(basic >= 10000, basic < 20000), DA + basic + (0.5 * HRA), DA + basic + HRA))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the IFS function. If you have all the data in a table, you can just copy what I did in the following [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YWUC97CVsX1-uet9-oo3AWWKSFjXpzQr49B0LzVcUjQ/edit?usp=sharing).

The full function would be:

```
=IFS(B2:B<10000, C2:C+B2:B, AND(B2:B>=10000, B2:B<20000), C2:C+B2:B+(0.5*D2:D), B2:B>=20000, C2:C+B2:B+D2:D)
```

Just take in consideration that Basic would be in column B, DA would be in column C, HRA would be in column D, and the result in column E.

You can just copy the spreadsheet to your own, and introduce the values you need.